# Unable to locate package libtomcrypt-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I can't seem to find this package when doing a simple `apt-get install libtomcrypt-dev`, the error I get is `unable to find the package libtomcryp-dev`.
Version I use is 14.04.02

I need it for my build, can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you have ?

Comment: "Can't seem to find" is not of much help. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/657599/edit) your question and add any specific errors, if any, that you are getting. In addition as hg8 asked, include which Ubuntu version are you using.

Comment: That package is located in the universe repository, at least in the one of Vivid (15.04). Have you enabled it (System Settings --> Software & Updates)? What Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Refer this http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtomcrypt-dev try downloading tar

Comment: Edited my previous post,  version is 14.04 and I had not enabled the universe repository, have enabled it jnow @byte commander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having enabled the Universe repository in <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>, you should be able to install the package `libtomcrypt-dev` with a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install libtomcrypt-dev
```

For more information about this package see [packages.ubuntu.com (14.04 Trusty - libtomcrypt-dev)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/trusty/libtomcrypt-dev).

Comment: Instead of writing "Thank you!", please find out how this site works by doing the 2-minutes [tour]. You will learn that on this site, you should accept an answer if it solves your problem. This gives both me and you a little reputation bonus (although mine will be bigger ;D). To accept an answer, you have to click on the grey tick symbol on the left of a question, below its vote counter, so that it becomes green. Thanks and welcome on AskUbuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry man, I didn't know that, thank you for letting me know and I'll take the tour .

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a ppa for this package, so here is how I would do it:

1) Download the .deb from here: [UbuntuUpdates - Package "libtomcrypt-dev"](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/universe/base/libtomcrypt-dev)

2) Install it with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/install-from-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt) for more information on how to install .deb files.